# Using $this when not in object context into the same class

Tags: php, class, static

I'm trying to build a View class for Smarty templates so I could call templates like in Laravel `View::make('template');`

But, for first time I'm getting this error. I found plenty of responses fixing the issue but I cannot fix mine. I don't know why so I'm starting to be little bit fed up... hehehehe

This is the class:

```
class View {

public $engine;
protected $tmpl_folder = 'tmpl';
protected $tmpl_compiled = 'tmpl_c';
protected $cache = true;
protected $force = true;

function __construct() {
    $this->engine = new Smarty();
    $this->engine->compile_check = $this->cache;
    $this->engine->force_compile = $this->force;
    $this->engine->template_dir = './' . $this->tmpl_folder . '/';
    $this->engine->compile_dir = './' . $this->tmpl_compiled;
}

static function make($t, $args = '') {
    if(!empty($args))
        $this->engine->assing($args);

    $this->engine->display($t.'.tpl');
    exit();
}}
```

Error is launching in method `make()`, `line <b>$this->engine->assing($args)</b>`.

- I tried to change declaration of $engine variable to public, private, protected and static... nothing...
- I declared make() like public, public static, like in the example above and the same with no "static".... nothing...
- I tried to change $this-> for self::... nothing...

I don't know what else can I do! Some advice please!

Comment: You can't call `$this` in a `static` method. Also, I'm assuming your `make` function is meant to be a factory method, which would typically do something like `return new View(...);`. The `exit()` is ... not sure what that is. Do you mean `assign` instead of `assing`? I don't normally say RTFM, but in your case, your code is so far from functional, I can't help but recommend you have a thorough look at [PHP Classes & Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: I'm with Naomik - It seems like you want to force people to use your constructor instead of the __construct method, which should indeed return a new view, or at least it seems like it

Comment: exit() was just for debuging, I took out static. Assing whas a gramatical mistake but is a greate typo as said Wee Zel hehehe!

Comment: Well, I don't want to force nobody of course!, just I'm not an expert so always I'm learning and trying my best! I will read the tutorial you've share me. Thanks bro, for now is woking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get this working quickly instantiate your View class as an object like this:

```
$obj_view = new View();
```

then make your call to the `make()` method like this:

```
$obj_view->make('template');
```

I'd also declare scope for your methods (functions) (both of them should be `public`) - you did it for the properties (variables), so why not for the methods as well and remove `static` from the `make()`

why are you calling `exit()` in `make()`? I hope this is for debug ('[Dead programs tell no lies](http://flylib.com/books/en/1.315.1.42/1/)')

`assing()` made me lol, a great typo! :)

TIP: avoid using bad language in code (in variable names, comments or debug) these are viewable by other developers and can, unintentionally, leak to the end user - it's not professional!

Comment: Thanks bro! and yes! exit() was only for debug ;)